# Spring data - RepositoryRestResource PUT returns 200 but does not update object

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm using Spring's HATEOAS repo:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "equipment", path = "equipment")
interface EquipmentRepository : PagingAndSortingRepository<Equipment, Int>
```

Here's my domain object:

```
@Entity
data class Equipment(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id: Int?,
    val serialNumber: String?,
    val modelNumber: String,
    val make: String,
    val model: String,
    val year: Int,
    val purchaseDate: Date,
    val warrantyEnds: Date,
    val cost: Double
)
```

I'm using cURL and Postman to create equipment and it's all good. If I use PATCH for a partial update the query updates the object - if I use the same URL and same data for PUT nothing is updated but I get a 200 response (and the old object) in postman.

How come I can PATCH `http://localhost:8080/equipment/1` works but a PUT with the same data and same endpoint returns 200 but does not update the data?

No errors on the server-side on the console/logs, or any indication as to why I'm getting a 200 and no update...

I am using Kotlin, if it matters...

[image: PUT not updating]

[image: PATCH is updating]

Answer (score 0):

Try change `val` to `var`, i had the same problem and this should help.